# Does Radon's theorem assume distinct $d+2$ points?

Tags: convex-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls

I'm reading [Wikipedia's proof for Radon's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%27s_theorem#Proof_and_construction) and wondering whether it still holds in case $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{d+2}$ aren't distinct.

Comment: If, say,$x_1=x_2$,  then take $a_1=1, a_2=-1$ and all the rest of the $a_i=0$.